# Cannot import materialize-css in React project to use Chips

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created project by command:

```
create-react-app app
```

I am using materialize-css http://materializecss.com/ and want to use Chips http://materializecss.com/chips.html.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'materialize-css';

class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.chips').material_chip({
                data: [{
                   tag: 'Apple',
                }, {
                   tag: 'Microsoft',
                }, {
                   tag: 'Google',
                }],
            });
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="chips"></div>
                <button>Add</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I have tried to import:

```
import 'materialize-css/bin/materialize.css'
import 'materialize-css/bin/materialize.js'
```

But it's not working. The browser throw error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).material_chip is not a function
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this in your entry JS file

```
import 'materialize-css'; // It installs the JS asset only
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
```

and you are done!

---

Update:
I have put all the necessary details to get your code working.  Try this out

`index.jsx` file is here

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'materialize-css';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.chips').material_chip({
        data: [{
          tag: 'Apple',
        }, {
          tag: 'Microsoft',
        }, {
          tag: 'Google',
        }],
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <div className="chips"></div>
          <button>Add</button>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

and `package.json` is like

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "font-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "materialize-css": "^0.97.8",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "redux": "3.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.15.0"
  }
```

and `webpack.config.js` is

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

  entry: [Screenshot from 2017-01-15 18-11-16
    "./src/index.jsx",
    "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000/",
    "webpack/hot/only-dev-server"
  ],

  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: __dirname + '/public'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './public',
    port: 3000
  },

  // Bundle lookup dir for included/imported modules
  // By default, bundler/webpack with search here for the scripts
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },


  // make sure you added babel-loader to the package
  // npm i babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-es2015 -D
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js[x]?$/, // Allowing .jsx file to be transpiled by babel
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loaders: [
        'style',
        'css?importLoaders=1',
        'font?format[]=truetype&format[]=woff&format[]=embedded-opentype'
      ] },
      { test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]' }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]

};
```

[image]
No error whatsoever.

Comment: @illusionist Having same issue with create-react-app.  Would I be correct to assume you had to eject in order to access webpack?

Comment: @illusionist I am not able to figure out the why checkbox integration with React in materailizecss is not working . Not able to solve it . Can you help

Answer (score 4):

With NPM:

Step 1: Install materialize

If you are using npm, make sure you install materialize using the command listed in their documentation:

```
npm install materialize-css@next
```

DON'T MISS the '**@nex**t' at the end. The installed version will be something like: "^1.0.0-rc.2" OR "^1.0.0-alpha.4"

Step 2: Import materialize:

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'

import M from 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js'
```

OR

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'

import M from 'materialize-css'
```

In order for the css import to work, you would need a *css loader*. Note that this loader is **already included** in projects built using **create-react-app** so you don't need the next steps. If instead, you are using custom webpack config, then run:

```
npm install --save-dev style-loader css-loader
```

Now add css-loader and style-loader in webpack config

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.join(__dirname, "build")
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["env", "react"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now you can initialize components individually, or all at once using M.AutoInit();

---

With CDN:

Add the following in your HTML file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Then, in the webpack config, add externals: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/